# result of evaluating block statement in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the simplest c++ statement declaring a variable "a":

```
int a = ({ int b = 10; b; });
```

As recent gcc and clang says, it's a valid statement which really declares variable `a` having value 10.

The question is: what is this? I know about various types of expressions. I know about various types of statements. But I can't find in a c++ 14 standard any mentioning that "block statement as an expression returns latest inner evaluated expression" or something like this.

Could somebody please point me exact lines of a standard saying that is code line is fully valid?

Comment: This is [not C++](https://godbolt.org/z/wHen12). If you want to be a language lawyer, you need to be `-pedantic`.

Comment: I added the language-lawyer tag because of the mention of finding the relevant C++ standard paragraph. I should have checked that it actually compiled first. My bad. Removed it.

Comment: So whether I understand you right that a fact of successful compilation of this line with g++ 5.4 and clang++ 6.0 ("clang++-6.8 -std=c++14 -Wall -o 1.out 1.cpp") is an extension of both compilers?

Upd: checked with -pedantic. Yes, a compiler says that is an extension.

Comment: A standard conforming way to do something like this would be to use a directly invoked lambda - like `int a = [] { int b = 10; return b; }();` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: what is this?

This is a GNU extension to ISO standard C, an extension that is available also for C++, but likewise is not part of ISO C++.

Citing the [GCC Manual: Chapter 6 - Extensions to the C Language Family](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html):

> ...
>
> These extensions are available in C and Objective-C. Most of them are also available in C++. ...
>
> - Statement Exprs: Putting statements and declarations inside expressions.

Where the latter is explained in detail in [GCC Manual: Section 6.1 - Statements and Declarations in Expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

> A compound statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as an expression in GNU C. This allows you to use loops, switches, and local variables within an expression.
>
> Recall that a compound statement is a sequence of statements surrounded by braces; in this construct, parentheses go around the braces. For example:
>
> ```
> ({ int y = foo (); int z;
>    if (y > 0) z = y;
>    else z = - y;
>    z; })
> ```
>
> is a valid (though slightly more complex than necessary) expression for the absolute value of `foo ()`.
>
> ...

As for Clang, the [Clang Language Extensions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) describes that Clang aims to support many GCC extensions: [*emhpasis* mine]:

> This document describes the language extensions provided by Clang. In addition to the language extensions listed here, *Clang aims to support a broad range of GCC extensions*. Please see the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) for more information on these extensions.